# Solidworks или Matlab для математического моделирования?

Tags: matlab, моделирование

Необходимо создать математическую модель движения жидкости по изогнутой трубе, найти наиболее нагруженные участки. Какую утилиту вы бы посоветовали исходя из данных задач?

Comment: Любое бесплатное (если задача не сложная) cfd приложение. Например вот такое https://sim-flow.com/tutorials/

Comment: Или вам нужно самому уравнения Навье-Стокса (соответствующие модели задачи) запрограммировать?

Comment: @AlexanderChernin да именно оно и нужно

Comment: пишите в матлабе, наверное :)